# Laravel - Controller Namespacing don't work

Tags: php, laravel, api, controller, routes

I started to develop with Laravel a few weeks ago. It's a great framework, especially for my purposes.

But at this point, I am confused about the functionality of Laravel. (I'm not pretty sure, if its a PHP or a Laravel problem).

I want to develop the API for my Webapplication. To keep my App Structure clean, I separate all API Controllers from the others, for which reason I gave the new Controllers a new Namespace.

When I gave my Controller the Namespace `"App\Http\Controllers\API"`, things go weird. It just gives me a blank site, independently of the code.

But when I remove API from the Namespace (`"App\Http\Controllers"`), the Controller works and generates the right output.

So, this Code don't work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Room;
use App\Http\Resources\Room as RoomResource;

class RoomsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $room = Room::all();
        return Response::json($room);
    }
}
```

And this Code works for me:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Room;
use App\Http\Resources\Room as RoomResource;

class RoomsAPIController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $room = Room::all();
        return Response::json($room);
    }
}
```

I just want to know, what I am doing wrong. The second method works but it seems to be a "quick and dirty" solution.

Comment: When you changed it to include `API` did you move it in the file system? Did you update the route to point at the new namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to be able to use that namespace, you should put these controllers in the API folder under Controllers.

`app/Http/Controllers/API` would have all your API controllers, and each of them inside this folder would need to add these lines to the top:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Then in your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file, you would need to change the namespace there as well like this:

```php
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\API') // <-- HERE
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Then you can use your routes like you would normally do like this:

```php
Route::get('rooms', 'RoomsAPIController@index')->name('rooms.index');
```

Or you can simply add `API\` infront of all your route actions, for example:

```php
Route::get('rooms', 'API\RoomsAPIController@index')->name('rooms.index');
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! It works. But its kind of weird. My first try was to rename my "api" folder to "API". When I did this, PhpStorm did some critical mess, cause at this point nothing works. But when I revert this change, it throws me a very useful exception instead of the blank site. I did your changes and change API\RoomsController@index to api\RoomsController@index and this works. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad it works! I prefer changing it to `Api` to stick to Laravel's naming convention. :)